# INSERT/UPDATE Blob on external database

Tags: blob, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to Insert/Update blob from one database to another. I know that Firebird contains [EXECUTE STATEMENT (on external database)](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd25-psql-execstat-on-external). But it does not work if you're trying to ins/upd blob into external database.

Does anybody know if it can be done with EXECUTE STATEMENT or any other suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

File is about 0,1MB big

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER WSATTACHMENT_AI0 FOR WSATTACHMENT
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE STATEMENT('INSERT INTO wsattachment(id, filecontent) VALUES(' || NEW.id || ',' || NEW.filecontent || ')')
  on external 'myDB.FDB'
  as user 'SYSDBA' password 'pw';
END
```

Error that I'm getting:

"Arithmetic overflow or division by zero has occurred.
arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation.
blob truncation when converting to a string: length limit exceeded."

Comment: How large is the content of the blob? Could you also include the code that you tried and any errors you get (if any)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I updated my question.

Comment: Is `filecontent` in both databases a blob?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes Mark it is.

Comment: Which Firebird 2.5 version are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wonder if something in field content could raise this error? Please see my comment bellow.

Comment: @ValMarinov I don't think so, not with a `length limit exceeded` as the error. The only thing I can think of is that some early version of Firebird 2.5 did some things wrong with blobs, where in some cases they where handled as `VARCHAR(30)` instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I changed from 2.5 to 2.5.5 and its now working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @skafinski Good to hear, but why 2.5.5, when 2.5.6 is the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameters instead.

See [EXECUTE STATEMENT with Dynamic Parameters](https://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rnfb25-psql-exctstmnt.html#rnfb25-psql-dynex)

Like :

```
EXECUTE STATEMENT('INSERT INTO wsattachment(id, filecontent) VALUES(:p1, :p2)')
(p1 := new.id, p2 := new.filecontent)
  on external 'myDB.FDB'
  as user 'SYSDBA' password 'pw';
```

Comment: same problem. Blob truncation when converting to a string: length limit exceeded

Comment: I tested with Firebird 2.5.5 and image in blob 2.5 Mb. Both blob fields are of subtype "binary".  Everithing is ok. When destination blob field is of subtype "text" there is  no error, but as expected the received image is broken.

Comment: Ok I updated FB from 2.5 to 2.5.5 and its now working great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some of the early versions of Firebird 2.5 had problems with blobs, for example in some cases blobs where handled has `VARCHAR(30)`. I can't easily identify the exact issue you have, but upgrading to a newer version should solve this problem (as you've already confirmed in the comments).

At the time of writing, Firebird 2.5.6 is the latest version, and 2.5.7 is expected soon.